# Service needed to get a customer's browser and OS information

Tags: language-agnostic

I know there is a service where you can send a private link to a customer and you get his browser and OS information via Email to solve bugs and support issues. But apparently this service's Google page rank is below zero, so I could not find it…

Does someone know the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon a new service that solves the problem and does even more: http://jooplicate.com